# SSRS Excel Export. Multi Tab

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I have an SSRS report I am exporting to excel. The  Export contains multiple tabs as they are grouped by a particular `Field!I`D and that is how they are named. The last tab appears named as `Field!ID.Value (2)`. Is there a way to name that tab specifically?

I have tried the following but with no luck.

```
=IIF( Last(Fields!ID.Value) = Fields!ID.Value,"Center Totals",IIF(Parameters!PARM.Value=true,Fields!ID.Value,"All Centers"))
```

Comment: Is `Fields!ID.Value` a null value in the last group?

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3527/export-sql-server-reporting-services-report-data-into-multiple-excel-worksheets/) to modify the tab names.

Comment: @aduguid   is not a null value, its actually a totals page of all the instead instead it just grabs a copy of the very last field populated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a page name to another group and calling the Global Page Name variable.